# Merge two lists in to one list and discard the duplicates. Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, unique, concatenation

Want to merge two lists and discard the intersecting elements

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

B = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Expected result:

```
['c', 'e', 'f']
```

I can get this by:

```
[i for i in A if i not in B] + [i for i in B if i not in A]
```

But is there a more convenient way to get the same result without loops and preferably through Pandas.

Best regards

Comment: Does the order of elements matter? If not, `list(set(A)^set(B))` is unbeatable. Using pandas for this task is _very_ expensive.

Comment: @DYZ, awesome and thank you! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sets:

```
set(A).symmetric_difference(B)
```

or equivalent:

```
set(A)^set(B)
```

(You can convert back to `list` if needs to be...)

Comment: Julien, much appreciated for the two approaches you provided! It will come really handy for the task I'm about to do.  May I ask how I could compute and compare the computational time between these two approaches, also @DYZ suggestion, and my clumsy list comprehension approach. I have tried the 'timeit' module but get either: AttributeError: module 'timeit' has no attribute 'list' or function' object has no attribute 'list'. Thanks again for the neat expressions :D

Comment: I believe these 2 are exactly the same, `^` is just a shortcut notation for the same function.